# What's the fxp?

Tags: networking, network-interface

When I read this [article](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fxp&sektion=4&n=1):

> fxp -- Intel EtherExpress PRO/100 Ethernet device driver

I have several questions about it:

1. I know Ethernet, but what's the EtherExpress?
2. what's PRO/100 mean? is the 100 mean 100Mbps?
3. there say `fxp` is `Ethernet device driver`, what's the meaning of `device driver`? is it a software?

Comment: If i were to guess Ether is shorthand for Ethernet.  **Intel EtherExpress PRO** is the name of the device series.  Your Ethernet device is a device and requires a driver to function.

Comment: how about the 100 ?

Comment: It's a 10/100 MB/sec Ethernet device. Most product names don't actually mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I know Ethernet, but what's the EtherExpress?

EtherExpress is the brand name for a series of network cards by Intel.

> 2. what's PRO/100 mean?

PRO/100 is the brand name for a network card from the mid-1990s in the EtherExpress family by Intel.

> is the 100 mean 100Mbps?

The Intel EtherExpress PRO/100 supports 10Base-T and 100Base-TX media types.

> 3. there say `fxp` is `Ethernet   device driver`, what's the meaning of `device driver`? is it a software?

A device driver is a piece of software that knows how to "talk to" a device. Without a device driver, a device is useless.